# Is there a way to collapse numeric rows by two variables while preserving non-numerical variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Need some help in R. Currently stuck solving the following task. I have the following sample table named `macula`

```
Initials  ExamDate        Eye       Layer    GCLR      GCLL     INLR     INLL
ON        01/01/2020      R         GCL      1.1       NA       NA       NA
ON        01/01/2020      L         GCL      NA        1.2      NA       NA
ON        01/01/2020      R         INL      NA        NA       1.3      NA
ON        01/01/2020      L         INL      NA        NA       NA       1.4
ON        11/11/2020      R         GCL      3.1       NA       NA       NA
ON        11/11/2020      L         GCL      NA        3.2      NA       NA
ON        11/11/2020      R         INL      NA        NA       3.3      NA
ON        11/11/2020      L         INL      NA        NA       NA       3.4
TH        02/01/2020      R         GCL      2.1       NA       NA       NA
TH        02/01/2020      L         GCL      NA        2.2      NA       NA
TH        02/01/2020      R         INL      NA        NA       2.3      NA
TH        02/01/2020      L         INL      NA        NA       NA       2.4
```

How do I get the following output where I collapse the rows by Lastname and Exam Date (since some people have multiple exam dates). I essentially need the following table:

```
Initials  ExamDate        GCLR      GCLL     INLR     INLL
ON        01/01/2020      1.1       1.2      1.3      1.4
ON        11/11/2020      3.1       3.2      3.3      3.4
TH        02/01/2020      2.1       2.2      2.3      2.4
```

I have tried the following code, but I just keep getting the error that I cannot sum character variables which makes sense.

```
try <- macula %>% select(.,
                 Lastname,
                 ExamDate,
                 GCLR)%>%
  group_by(Lastname,ExamDate) %>%summarise_all(funs(sum))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
macula %>%
  select(-Eye, -Layer) %>%
  group_by(Initials, ExamDate) %>%
  summarise_all(~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   Initials ExamDate    GCLR  GCLL  INLR  INLL
#   <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ON       01/01/2020   1.1   1.2   1.3   1.4
# 2 ON       11/11/2020   3.1   3.2   3.3   3.4
# 3 TH       02/01/2020   2.1   2.2   2.3   2.4
```

Your comment of *"cannot sum character variables"* suggests that the last four columns are not all `numeric`. If you're confident that all should be numbers (there aren't other numbers in there), and/or are willing to take the jump and assume it to be the case, then you can use `as.numeric` to the call

```r
macula %>%
  select(-Eye, -Layer) %>%
  group_by(Initials, ExamDate) %>%
  summarise_all(~ sum(as.numeric(.x), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```